# ¿Cómo arreglar error usando el tema WP Residence en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

He estado editando las partes de Características y servicios de las propiedades. En una de esas ediciones de categorías me doy cuenta que ya no se puede publicar.

¿A alguien le ha pasado este error? De ser así, ¿qué pudo haber pasado?

Adjunto fotografía de lo que ve el usuario al tratar de publicar una propiedad.

[image: Aquí se puede apreciar cómo no deja seleccionar otros detalles de la propiedad como precio, ubicación, servicios...]

Comment: pareciera que el cpt no "traduce" el campo "nombre(obligatorio)" al campo title, o no está generando un title para el custom post type. el title define el slug x eso es obligatorio al usar permalinks. fijate en la db si guarda el campo "nombre" en los titles o si es un meta en todo caso podes revisar una instalacion limpia a ver que cosas podes ir modificando sin q se rompa y enviar un bug report

Comment: Gracias, eso haré